# Using an array inside a map = { [ ] } in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, console.log

It doesn't seem possible to declare a map like that, is there some way to do it?

I want this kind of functionality:

```
var map = {[]}; // doesn't compile

map["first"] = [1,2,3];
map["second"][0] = 4;
map["second"][1] = 5;

console.log(map["first"][1]);   // I want it to print 2 here
console.log(map["second"][1]);  // should print 5
```

Is there a way to get a map similar to this?

Comment: Works for me (in chrome console)

Comment: Oh it did, but how do I declare it? var map = {[]}; doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work perfectly.

**EDIT**: To add a new array to an object, you need to add a new array to the object:

```
map.second = [];
```

If you're not sure whether it exists yet, you can check:

```
if (!map[someKey]) map[someKey] = [];
```

Comment: This is a comment....

Comment: @Sam: It also fully answers the question

Comment: The question isn't a real question, and so should be closed, not "answered".

Comment: Oh it did, but how do I declare it? var map = {[]}; doesn't seem to work

Comment: @user2010496: The same way you did in your question.

Comment: But if I need to dynamically add data (check my updated question)

Comment: Thanks, works now! And it should be declared var map = {}; as in the normal way